# Terminating a Windows Service on an unhandled Task (TPL) exception

Tags: c#, windows-services, task-parallel-library, task

My Windows Service spawns various Tasks. I wire up each task with a continuation to execute only in the event of an unhandled exception: `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted`.

How should I correctly terminate the Service in this continuation? I don't want to keep the service running due to the unexpected error. I also want to exit the service in a way that allows me to make use of the Windows Service recovery options - potentially having the service restarted.

I am currently calling `Environment.FailFast`. Is this the best solution?

Comment: Why not gracefully call `OnStop`?

Comment: If I do that, can the service be restarted automatically? I also figure OnStop will let the application run for a short while longer while a gracefully terminate the remaining threads/tasks. Might it be safer just to bail out immediately?

Comment: The *default* behaviour when a task throws an exception and nothing observes it is for the process to be torn down. What are you trying to add beyond what the system already would provide for you if you wrote less code?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever This is not true for .Net 4.5 and above or when you handle the task in an `OnlyOnFaulted` continuation.

Comment: Using .Net 4.0. I thought the default behavior is that the process is only torn down when GC invokes the task's fianlizer - which is nondeterministic? Edit: this in situations where the fault is not 'observed'.

Comment: @MrNick Indeed. And only if you don't handle the exception with a continuation.